# Construction of a vector consisting of entries with a peculiar pattern

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, puzzle

*Note: A similar problem was asked in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352240/constructing-a-vector-consisting-of-nonnegative-entries/352401), but no importance was attached to order of nonzero numbers and zeros*

Consider constructing a $n$-tuple of numbers $v=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ consisting of nonnegative integers  such that it consists of $m$ nonzero entries, $a_1=1$ and, if $a_j$'s are nonzero, then $a_j\equiv a_{n-j+2}+j-1 \pmod m $, ; with the additional constraint that all nonzero $a_i$'s are distinct modulo $m$. The places of the nonzero numbers  (the $j$s) and zeros are chosen in a fixed predetermined order. For example, suppose $n=20$, $m=11$ and the order of nonzero numbers is $\{1,*,0,*,*,*,0, *,0,0,0,0,0,*,0,*,*,*,0,*\}$, then we can find the numbers satisfying the congruence as $(1,11,0,8,7,9,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,4,3,5,0,10)$. If $n=7$, $m=5$, and the order of nonzero numbers and zeros is $\{1,*,*,0,0,*,*\}$, we can find it as $(1,4,2,0,0,5,3)$   Note that  the number $m$ itself appears once as a nonzero number satisfying the above congruence.

Is it always possible to construct such a vector for any given $n, m$ and order of nonzero numbers and zeros? I think this should be possible if $m\le n$ is odd.  It is easy to construct if the order of nonzero and zeros were consecutive  (within $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$) . But, in other cases of nonzero and zero patterns, it is not clear as to how to proceed with the construction. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Yes, I just wrote the same question, but I hope you get my point, we choose some places before $\frac{n}{2}$, where we have to fill the numbers from $2$ to $m$ such that the numbers after $\frac{n}{2}$ are determined. Slightly edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be posed as a [maximum independent set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)).

Let $D$ be the set of values for differences $a_j-a_{n-j+2}$ allowed  by the given pattern.
Consider a graph $G$ with the vertex set:
$$V = \{ (a,b) \in \{2,3,\dots,m\}^2\ :\ ((a-b)\bmod m)\in D \}$$
and two vertices $(a_1,b_1)\ne (a_2,b_2)$ are connected with an edge whenever $\{a_1,b_1\}\cap\{a_2,b_2\}\ne\emptyset$ or $a_1-b_1\equiv a_2-b_2\pmod{m}$.

Let $S$ be the maximum independent set. It is clear that $|S|\leq |D|$. When $|S|=|D|$, $S$ contains exactly one pair $(a,b)$ for each difference from $D$, and these pair are disjoint as sets. Hence, they can be placed to the corresponding positions in the pattern to deliver a solution.

---

Here is a [sample SageMath code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdkM1qxSAQhfd5irmLlhlqQtIfChfcXcgbZCMSQp20hsZeYnRT-u7VSKHtLHTm4DnzoeEZIr-ME67iQucKUg0gQaEVC8H8sYEF6wDvm2Yt8_JrtjOgrRe6WbN40Ye_T_5-m65vqAahtKZDzdaQXw1ly48W_2m5Umw4yQiTM4Dv7NDzjoFu8xWJTrKF5MSgWl0H1ek6pu4upi6RSNnS37gDqpmMGdm8MgYRC9LGe9gcfAL6nOSLH87gDzKfyfrGOsNXTofbxwxA8FVV5c-6TqhOPIhH8SSeNX0DDvJXqA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) that for a given $m$ and a difference set $D$, computes the corresponding disjoint pairs of elements.

For a given example with $m=11$ and $D = \{ 1, 3,4,5, 7\}$ it gives the following corresponding disjoint pairs:

```
{1: (3, 2), 7: (4, 8), 4: (9, 5), 3: (10, 7), 5: (11, 6)}
```

---

In some cases the problem allows explicit solution. For example, when $D\cap \{ (-d)\bmod m\ :\ d\in D\}=\emptyset$, a solution can be derived from [my construction](https://mathoverflow.net/q/352401) for the previous question.

Comment: thanks! so the decidability that a construction exists for a given pattern is NP-complete right?

Comment: @vidyarthi: No, I reduced your problem to NP-complete one, but this does not prove that your problem itself is NP-complete (for this we'd need reduction in the opposite direction). So, it's quite possible that a polynomial-time algorithm still exists, and I just did not see it.